# What do ripples on the water indicate?

Tags: stardew-valley

Occasionally while fishing in Stardew Valley, I'll see ripples on the surface of the water (little animated circles). Does this indicate the presence of a rare type of fish? Are my fishing chances higher in that location? What does it indicate (if anything)?

The screenshot below illustrates what I'm talking about:

[image: Ripples on the water]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot? Pretty sure I know what you mean, but want to be sure.,

Comment: [Is this the ripples you speak of? not the best screenshot, but I think it's what you're referring to](http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/306614004554213225/FD8E074DE0D6767DD08452C91A2D99E37AB44A1D/).

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm talking about. I've added a screenshot above.

Comment: Excellent. It's gotta have something to do with fish, but I've never had  fishing rod with me when I've seen them. I'll need to start carrying one all the time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The bubbles you occasionally see indicate a higher activity of fish in that tile. If you successfully land your lure within or close to that bubbling tile when fishing, you will get a visual confirmation with the water splashing. The area for the benefit slightly extends outside of the tile, and the different visual effects can be seen below:

[image: Fishing Bubbles Visual Effect]

[image: Standard Fishing Visual Effect]

Note: The Standard Fishing Visual Effect is also displayed when the bobber hits the water.

When fishing from the ripples, you will notice that fish and other debris bite much quicker. With lures and bait, you will find fish biting within the first 5 seconds of fishing.

Answer (score -1):

Yah, its for quicker bites. If you see them, use them (if possible). This is especially useful for River fishing as you can always reach them. What I do is if I am going on Fishing Expeditions and need quantity of fish over quality, I go River Fishing. Now if I want quality....

...I go to Lakes and Ocean and fish in the darker water areas. There are prime locations that are good for quality gold-star fish and if you scroll down on this page... http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Fish ...then you will find many locations you probably didn't even think about fishing at. There is also a table at the bottom that defines what time of the day you should start fishing and end fishing for a specific type of fish at certain locations during specific seasons. I recommend taking a look at those tables.